# Object Tracking with YOLOv4 and DeepSORT: Merging Results from Two Videos

Tags: python, computer-vision, yolov4

I'm working on a project where I use YOLOv4 for object detection and DeepSORT for tracking objects in videos. Initially, I process the first part of the video and successfully track objects.

Now, I need to extend this tracking to a second part of the video, ensuring continuity for objects detected in both videos. I'm struggling with the merging process and maintaining consistency between the two runs of the object tracker.

So far, I've looked into saving the `tracks` of objects that have `track.is_confirmed` equal to `True` but I don't think I'm doing it right as `track.feature` is always empty. I don't know what information I need to save or how to load the correct information.

Can someone guide me on the best approach for merging the results of the object tracker between two videos using YOLOv4 and DeepSORT? Any insights, code examples, or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Edit: https://github.com/theAIGuysCode/yolov4-deepsort is where I'm getting the code from.

Comment: Can you provide more info on the tracking data format? What does DeepSORT output? Ideally, you would get data like some CSV with: `time,object_id,position` for each frame of the video - which you could write some code to manually link objects between videos.

Comment: Additionally, would it be possible to simply merge the multiple video parts together, and run this algorithm once? Or would the video be too long / files too large?

Comment: @mimocha Combining the videos would make them too large, unfortunately. Also, don't want to run the code and have it crash midway through for whatever reason so this is an inbuilt way of checkpointing. The issue is I don't quite know what to use to checkpoint. DeepSORT can output a video with all the bounding boxes drawn on the objects while they are tracked. So it has data on the ID of a tracked object, bounding boxes information, track information, a tracker, etc. The thing is I don't know which ones I need and how to keep track of them for the next video to avoid duplicate tracking.